# Same task to be done inside multiple binded KnockoutJs subscribe function

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am working on KnockoutJs and I have used valueUpdate:'afterkeydown' with textboxes and valueUpdate: 'change' with select elements to subscribe the respective changes and do SAME task. I want to call a same function via subscribe after each of their value changes.

To make it more clear, I'm onto something like below:

```
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: val1, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: val2, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/>
    <select data-bind="value: sel1, valueUpdate:'change'">
    <select data-bind="value: sel2, valueUpdate:'change'">
```

And in javascript, I've subscribed every changes like this:

```
viewModel.val1.subscribe(function () {
            doSameWork();
        });
viewModel.val2.subscribe(function () {
            doSameWork();
        });
viewModel.sel1.subscribe(function () {
            doSameWork();
        });
viewModel.sel2.subscribe(function () {
            doSameWork();
        });


################################

var doSameWork = function(){  alert('some work done!');  };
```

If I'm calling same function with every valueUpdate, then I was wondering if there is any way to subscribe every valueUpdate in a single subscribe(saving LOC) or anything like that rather than subscribing four value updates separately if I have to do same thing with each of them. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create only one event handler and "share" it to all observables

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.onValueChanged = function (newValue) {
        // your task
        alert('some work done!');
    };

    self.val1 = ko.observable();
    self.val1.subscribe(self.onValueChanged);
    self.val2 = ko.observable();
    self.val2.subscribe(self.onValueChanged);
    self.sel1 = ko.observable();
    self.sel1.subscribe(self.onValueChanged);
    self.sel2 = ko.observable();
    self.sel2.subscribe(self.onValueChanged);

};
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TywhY/)

@Accssharma :

The first time a computed is evaluated, the ko engine detects dependencies between observables and computeds. So when you write this :

```
ko.computed(function(){ val1(); val2(); sel1(); sel2(); doSameWork(); });
```

Ko registers val1, val2 sel1 and sel2 as a dependency of the computed.
This means if val1 or val2.. changed the computed may change too.
So when an observable (eg  val1) is changed the computed needs to be evaluated.
That's why the doSameWork function is called.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Damien, I tried but it didn't work that way. But, I found another solution using `ko.computed(function(){ val1(); val2(); sel1(); sel2(); doSameWork(); });`. :)

Comment: Now it works.But the workaround may works it is not good.
It creates dependencies between val1, val2, sel1, sel2 and a computed.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Can you please elaborate with what types of dependencies u meant? :).Thanks.

Comment: Actually, for this particular case, dependencies wouldn't matter because every value change has to be figured out firing a same function. And, thanks for sharing your bit. :)